# write data in excel using batch file

Tags: excel, batch-file

I write a batch file that check a folder that contains some fonts.I want to to write them in excel.but when I run the .bat file, values overwrite the first row?Actually I don't know how to go to the next row!
would anyone help me?
This is the code:

```
@ echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
color 0b

set file=C:\Users\S.R.P\Desktop\input\*
set inpDir=C:\Users\S.R.P\Desktop\input\


set dat=Test.csv
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
set fontname=%%~ni && set fontname=!fontname: =!
ECHO !fontname!

set fileextension=%%~xi
set  fontfile=!fontname!%%~xi
set outDir=C:\Users\S.R.P\Desktop\ouput\!fontname!\
ECHO !inpDir!%%~ni
echo !fontfile!
ren "!inpDir!%%~ni%%~xi" "!fontfile!"
ECHO !outDir!
ECHO !fontname!!fileextension!
echo "!fontname!","!inpDir!%%~ni">%dat%

echo.>>%dat%
)
pause
```

Comment: don't choose [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) `>` and `>>` by random. The first overwrites, the second appends.

Comment: Why not write a VBA code to do the job if you want to write to an Excel file?

Comment: Change `echo "!fontname!","!inpDir!%%~ni">%dat%` to `echo "!fontname!","!inpDir!%%~ni">>%dat%`. To make sure that the file starts empty, just before the `FOR` loop, add `TYPE NUL>"%dat%"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>"test.csv" (
  for %%i in ... (
    ...
    ...
  )
)
```

and remove all `>%dat%` inside the `for` loop.
Also, this opens the file only once, whereas each *>* or *>>* will open and close the file.

if you want to print data in the console, then `echo ...>con`

Comment: Exactly! +1 **`;)`** I used to place input redirections _at beginning_ of the block and output redirections _at end_ of block. I think it is somewhat clearer this way...